# Numbers with Chemfig

Tags: chemistry

[image]

How can I put a red 1 above the N?

$\chemfig{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-=--=)}$

Answer (score 2):

chemfig does not need to be in math mode.
To place something above, below, or anywhere else around an atom, use `\charge`

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \setcharge{extra sep=4pt}
    \chemfig{*6(-\charge{270=H,90=\textcolor{red}1}{N}-=--=)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The user asked another question: when using the code below.

```
$\setcharge{extra sep=7pt} \chemfig{*6(-\charge{270=H,352=\textcolor{red}8}{N}-*6(-\charge{270=H,90=\ textcolor{red}1}{N}-=--=)----\charge{270=\textcolor{red}7})}$
```

the number "7" did not appear in the lower right corner of the ring (see the figure in the original question above).

First, we must remember that Chemfig always draws rings in a counterclockwise direction, and starts right at the point where the number "7" is in the image.

But after placing the last chemical bond in the ring, it is not possible to insert anything else in the ring. As the code `charge{270=\textcolor{red}7}` is after the last bond, it will be ignored.

For this code to take effect, it must be the first code inside the ring.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\setcharge{extra sep=7pt} \chemfig{*6(\charge{270=\textcolor{red}7}{}-\charge{270=H,352=\textcolor{red}8}{N}-* 6(-\charge{270=H,90=\textcolor{red}1}{N}-=--=)----)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you help me to write this in Discord with the Texit Bot?

Comment: I wanna say thanks, this helped a lot already

Comment: U have an idea how you could do it with the 7?

Comment: I thried this $\setcharge{extra sep=7pt}
\chemfig{*6(-\charge{270=H,352=\textcolor{red}8}{N}-*6(-\charge{270=H,90=\textcolor{red}1}{N}-=--=)----\charge{270=\textcolor{red}7})}$ but no 7 is showing up

Comment: Put "\charge{270=\textcolor{red}7}{}"  at the beginning of the ring, not at the end, and you need to put "{}" at the end with \charge -->       \setcharge{extra sep=7pt} \chemfig{*6(\charge{270=\textcolor{red}7}{}-\charge{270=H,352=\textcolor{red}8}{N}-*6(-\charge{270=H,90=\textcolor{red}1}{N}-=--=)----)}